# Spring rest controller - XML Schema Definition

Tags: java, spring, jaxb

**Objective**

- Spring rest controller insert method get requested with an xml body.
- The xml body is validate by a xsd local server file.
- Jaxb unmarshal the xml to the specified class.

**Dummy situation**

Spring version: 4.2.4.RELEASE

```
@RestController
public class DummyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Dummy insert(@RequestBody Dummy dummy) {
        return dummy;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "dummy")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Dummy {
    @XmlElement private ADummy aDummy;
    @XmlElement private BDummy bDummy;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "alpha")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ADummy {
    @XmlElement private String value;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "beta")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BDummy {
    @XmlElement private String value;
}
```

And a xsd file more strict than the Jaxb rules on classes.

**Current result and problem**

- Spring rest controller recieve the request, and unmarshal to a Dummy instance
- *Problem: cannot validate with xsd*

**I tried**

1 -
I tried to specify the schema into spring-servlet.xml as proposed [here](https://devilspace.org/2013/07/05/how-to-make-xsd-validation-in-a-rest-based-web-service-xml-request-by-using-xsd-file-and-jaxbmarshaller/)

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound" value="Dummy"/>
    <property name="schema" value="stb.xsd"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Elaborate on "cannot validate with xsd". What exactly do you do (code), what exactly is not working, which specific exceptions or errors you get.

Comment: I just mean that I didn't figure any solution for now

Comment: How do you create your unmarshaller? You just need to [set a schema](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/jaxb/Jaxb2Marshaller.html#setSchema-org.springframework.core.io.Resource-) wheb you create it.

Comment: Spring does it with [@RequestBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html)

Comment: But still there is a configuration or autoconfiguration somewhere. You need to reconfigure the unmarshaller.

Comment: That's what I tried unsuccessfully in the spring-servlet